# Declare and concatenate a variable in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

so i want to pass several values to a stored procedure.  then bases on those values, add to a variable that would then be set as my where clause.  but im stumped and google aint helping.  here is what i have/my idea

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_RunReport @TransType varchar(255), @Accounts varchar(75)
AS

--declare a varchar WHERE clause variable here

IF @TransType <> ''
--add to WHERE clause variable

iF @Accounts <>''
--add to WHERE clause variable

SELECT * 
    FROM log
WHERE --my WHERE clause
```

GO

i dont see how this is possible.  i can do it all in c sharp in the front end, but i feel like it should be done and can be done in the stored procedure.  any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: See exec_sql: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

Comment: i think i was just missing the bloody declares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While dynamic SQL in previous answer is perhaps fine, I would suggest this "pure" SQL approach

```
WHERE TransType = ISNULL(@TransType, TransType)
    AND Accounts = ISNULL(@Accounts, Accounts)
```

There is some room to optimize performance by getting rid of ISULL (not optimal when used in WHERE clause), but this should give you the idea.

Of course, insteead of `AND` your logic may reuire an `OR` and also you need to ensure that params are "properly" empty (NULL in my case or whatever will constitute "empty" if you re-write this to remove the ISNULL)

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic SQL using `EXEC`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_RunReport @TransType varchar(255), @Accounts varchar(75)
AS

DECLARE @where VARCHAR(4000) = ' WHERE 1=1'
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000)

IF @TransType <> ''
    SET @where = @where + ' AND TransType = ''' + @TransType + ''''

IF @Accounts <>''
    SET @where = @where + ' AND Accounts = ''' + @Accounts + ''''

SET @sql = 'SELECT * 
    FROM log' + @where

exec (@sql)
```

Or using `sp_executesql` which is recommended:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_RunReport @TransType varchar(255), @Accounts varchar(75)
AS

DECLARE @where NVARCHAR(4000) = N' WHERE 1=1'
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500) = N'@TransType varchar(255), @Accounts varchar(75)'

IF @TransType <> ''
    SET @where = @where + N' AND TransType = @TransType'

IF @Accounts <>''
    SET @where = @where + N' AND Accounts = @Accounts'

SET @sql = N'SELECT * 
    FROM log' + @where

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, @ParmDefinition,
                  @TransType = @TransType, @Accounts = @Accounts
```